# Fourier transform of distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\in S_{\infty}$ be a Schwartz function and let us define a linear functional,for any $\varphi\in S_{\infty}$, $S_{\infty}\to\mathbb{C}$, $\varphi\mapsto (f,\varphi)$ by$$(f,\varphi):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\varphi d\mu$$where $\mu$ is the usual linear Lebesgue measure. I read in Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis* ([p. 453](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) that, if we call the Fourier trasnform operator $F:f\mapsto\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-i\lambda x}d\mu_x$, then$$2\pi(f,\varphi)=(F[f],F[\varphi])$$*accordingly with [Plancherel theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Plancherel_theorem)*. I know a corollary of Plancherel theorem (p. 442 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) according to which $$\forall f_1,f_2\in L_2(-\infty,\infty)\quad\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_1 \bar{f_2}d\mu=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}F[f_1]\overline{F[f_2]}d\mu$$therefore I would say that $2\pi(f,\bar{\varphi})=(F[f],\overline{F[\varphi]})$, but I am not sure how $2\pi(f,\varphi)=(F[f],F[\varphi])$ can hold... Is it valid for real valued functions only? Even if $\varphi=\bar{\varphi}$, I do not think that $F[\varphi]$ is real valued if $\varphi$ is, in general. Could anybody give a proof of $2\pi(f,\varphi)=(F[f],F[\varphi])$? (I am assuming that there is not a typographical error in the book, but it is not impossible that there is one). I heartily thank you!

After stating that, the text says that $2\pi(f,\varphi)=(F[f],F[\varphi])$ holds not only for $f\in S_\infty$, but for any $f\in L_1(-\infty,\infty)$, while I did not even know that, such a generic function, $F[f]\cdot F[\varphi]$ is summable...

Comment: I think they're using inner product notation $(f,g)=\int f\overline{g}\,dx$. The Fourier transform is unitary on $L^{2}$ with this inner product, which is equivalent to $(Ff,Fg)=(f,g)$ in inner product notation.

Comment: @T.A.E. Quite strangely, since in the chapter introducing distributions $(f,\varphi):\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\varphi(x) dx$, but it isn't the first inconsistence of use that I find in the book. As to the validity of that formula for any $f\in L^1$, $\varphi\inS_\infty$ how can we be sure that $\int f\varphi d\mu$ exists (assumed it isn't a typo)? I $\infty$-ly thank you!

Comment: Schwartz class functions are better than $L^{\infty}$ because the functions and all their derivatives are rapidly decreasing. And, by design, this class of functions is mapped to itself under the Fourier transform. So $f\varphi$ is in $L^{1}$ if $f \in L^{1}$, and $(Ff)(F\varphi)$ is integrable as well because $Ff \in L^{\infty}$.